# UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter requires loginProcessingUrl = "/login"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I tried setting [..].formLogin().[..].loginProcessingUrl() to something else than /login in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapterfilter, and the result is that attemptAuthentication() in my custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is not called.

If I set th:action="@{/login}" in the form, the function is called, but the login won't work (since I specified another processing url in the security class).

Comment: It have to be the same URL in your configuration and in your form.

Comment: When I do have the same URL in the configuration and the form, and it is not /login, attemptAuthentication() is not called. That only happens when it is set to /login, it's *always* called when the form is set to /login, even though the configuration is not.